# Bootstrap modal not displaying and behaving as expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've copied and pasted the example code from twitter bootstrap to create a basic modal window in my WordPress portfolio site.

```
<div class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;  </button>
  <h3>Modal header</h3>
  <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <div class="modal-footer">
</div>
```

Initially the box appears visible on document load which is not desired. It cannot be dismissed when the cross button or close button is clicked on.

The contact button is where I added the modal trigger button
code,

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
```

when clicking on this button, the background goes darker as desired, the box can then be closed. However after this event, the main navigation cannot be used. I imagine there is a simple conflict somewhere. Any suggestions on how to trouble shoot would be welcome. The site is at http://sandpit.jonathanbeech.co.uk/

Comment: did you add bootstrap css and js files?

Comment: Those are present and I checked in view source, they appear to be showing up and loading properly. I wonder if there are existing previous styles conflicting. An initial look at the css with the inspect element of Google Chrome seems to indicate that isn't the case.

Comment: @JonathanBeech - If possible, remove all other js libs loaded in your <head> except what you need to run bootstrap and see if that resolves it. I have seen custom JqueryUI type libs interfere with BS because of namespace issues. http://dullsharpness.com/2013/04/29/resolve-jqueryui-and-twitter-bootstrap-button-conflict/

Comment: @JonathanBeech Yes I was inspecting it too, what I did see is that you are missing an entry in Bootstrap CSS for the hide class, that's why the modal appears on page load `.hide{display:none}`. But that didn't solve the issue with it not working properly. I think it may be a JS conflict as @cerd suggested. One other thing to try is to load the complete Bootstrap JS and CSS, because I noticed you only had the modal components

Comment: Many thanks I will take a look soon and update where I'm up to.

Comment: @koala_dev downloading the rest of the components did the trick and it now works fine. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Remove class `hide` from modal div:

   `<div class="modal` <strike>`hide`</strike> `fade">`
2. Add an `id` attribute to modal div: `id="myModal"`